# Auth Component login issue on Linux

Tags: cakephp

I've been working with CakePHP for sometime now, specifically using the Auth component. I have several running instances of the current web app I'm working on, all of them installed on  various Linux machines.

This morning I was denied access to two of the instances. The odd thing is I did not change anything since yesterday.

I'm pretty sure there's no database issue, the logs look exactly the same as before. The only difference is that instead of redirecting me to the home page, I keep getting redirected back to my login page. The other difference is now I never get the flash message that's set in the 'authError' member of the Auth component.

Some other stuff I tried is to clean browsing data from my browser, restart Apache and reboot my machines.

One other piece of information is that both misbehaving machines are VMs running on my desktop PC.

Answer (score 0):

This can be session issue. Check if time on VMs is correct. It is possible that session expires instantly if client time is diffrent than server's time....

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thanks. The date on both VMs changed to yesterday's for some reason. Once I set it right everything got back to normal.

Comment: great, now You should accept the answer ;)